# How to restrict viewing of php.ini from all subdirectories?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm currently able to alter `.htaccess` file as such to prevent opening of the `php.ini` and other files via a web browser:

```
# Prevent .ini and other files from being open from web browser
<filesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</filesMatch>
```

But this seems to work only for the root directory, where I place this `.htaccess` file, so if I navigate to `www.mysite.com/sub/php.ini` it can still open that file.

Any idea how to make a filter for all such files in all subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to your apache configuration `httpd.conf`, or to your `.htaccess` itself.

```
<Files "*.ini">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Or this would work as well:

```
<Files "*.ini">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

If you want to keep it the format you have at the moment, you could do this:

```
<filesMatch ".*\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: And if I want to do other files as well, do I set the filter as such: `*.ini|*.log|*.sh` and so on?

Comment: @c00000fd I've updated my answer to add the 3rd option where it's from where you started.

Comment: Oh, cool. thanks! It's just like a regular expression, correct?

Comment: Yes it is @c00000fd! :)